# Send request with custom cookie Volley

Tags: android, networking, android-volley

I looked at some questions regarding this issue with no success so far

I want to send http request with custom cookie using Volley library

This is how i set the cookie:

```
CookieManager cm = new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
    CookieHandler.setDefault(cm);
    Map<String,List<String>> header = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add("name=value");
    header.put("Set-Cookie", values);
    try {
        cm.put(new URI(uri), header);
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("TEST",e.getMessage().toString());
    }
```

After that i send this request:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(BASE_URL +url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                {
                    Log.i("TEST", response.toString());


                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.i("TEST", "ERROR: " + error.toString());

                }
            } ... 
   AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest, tag_json_obj);
```

I also tried setting the cookie in the headers section like this:

```
@Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String,String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put("Cookie", "name=value");
            return headers;

        }
```

But, from server side i am logging the request and it seems like the cookie is not set:

> validate { cookie: 
>      { path: '/',
>        _expires: null,
>        originalMaxAge: null,
>        httpOnly: true },
>     passport: {} }

What seems to be the problem?